# Java: Typecasting to Generics

Tags: java, generics, class, casting

This method that uses method-level generics, that parses the values from a custom POJO, `JXlistOfKeyValuePairs` (which is exactly that). The only thing is that both the keys and values in `JXlistOfKeyValuePairs` are `String`s.

This method wants to taken in, in addition to the `JXlistOfKeyValuePairs` instance, a `Class<T>` that defines which data type to convert the values to (assume that only `Boolean`, `Integer` and `Float` are possible). It then outputs a `HashMap` with the specified type for the values in its entries.

This is the code that I have got, and it is obviously broken.

```
private <T extends Object>  Map<String, T>
    fromListOfKeyValuePairs(JXlistOfKeyValuePairs jxval, Class<T> clasz)
{
    Map<String, T> val = new HashMap<String, T>();
    List<Entry> jxents = jxval.getEntry();
    T value;
    String str;
    for (Entry jxent : jxents)
    {
        str = jxent.getValue();
        value = null;
        if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class))
        {
            value = (T)(Boolean.parseBoolean(str));
        } else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))
        {
            value = (T)(Integer.parseInt(str));
        } else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Float.class))
        {
            value = (T)(Float.parseFloat(str));
        }
        else {
            logger.warn("Unsupported value type encountered in key-value pairs, continuing anyway: " +
                clasz.getName());
        }
        val.put(jxent.getKey(), value);
    }
    return val;
}
```

This is the bit that I want to solve:

```
if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class))
{
    value = (T)(Boolean.parseBoolean(str));
} else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))
{
    value = (T)(Integer.parseInt(str));
}
```

I get: `Inconvertible types required: T found: Boolean`

Also, if possible, I would like to be able to do this with more elegant code, avoiding Class#isAssignableFrom.

Any suggestions?

---

Sample method invocation:

```
Map<String, Boolean> foo = fromListOfKeyValuePairs(bar, Boolean.class);
```

---

Solved, thanks to both @Chris Dolan and @polygenelubricants. The cause was the typecast was getting confused when combine with the autoboxing of the primitive. Compiler warnings are avoided because the method parameter `clasz` is of the type `Class<T>`, instead of just `Class` or `Class<?>`, so invoking the `cast` method was typesafe.

Impl. soln.:

```
private <T extends Object> Map<String, T> fromListOfKeyValuePairs(
    JXlistOfKeyValuePairs jxval, Class<T> clasz)
{
    Map<String, T> val = new HashMap<String, T>();
    List<Entry> jxents = jxval.getEntry();
    T value;
    String str;
    for (Entry jxent : jxents)
    {
        str = jxent.getValue();
        value = null;
        if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class))
        {
            value = clasz.cast(Boolean.parseBoolean(str));
        }
        else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))
        {
            value = clasz.cast(Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(str)));
        }
        else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Float.class))
        {
            value = clasz.cast((Object)Float.parseFloat(str));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.warn("Unsupporteded value type encountered in key-value pairs, continuing anyway: " +
                clasz.getName());
        }
        val.put(jxent.getKey(), value);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Class<T>.cast` method instead of doing your own unchecked `(T)` cast.

```
    if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)) {
        value = clasz.cast(Boolean.parseBoolean(str));
    } else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
        value = clasz.cast(Integer.parseInteger(str));
    } else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Float.class)) {
        value = clasz.cast(Float.parseFloat(str));
    }
```

No compiler warning.

---

As for why the original code doesn't compile, it's because you're trying to cast a primitive **directly** to an unknown reference type. Casting **directly** from primitive to a reference type only works in very specific cases, and in all those cases, the type *must be known* at compile time.

```
    Object o;

    o = (Integer) 42; // works! Boxing conversion!
    o = (Number) 42;  // works! Autoboxing then widening reference conversion!
    o = (Object) 42;  // works! Autoboxing then widening reference conversion!
    o = 42; // YES! This also compiles!!!

    o = (String) ((Object) 42); // compiles fine!
    // will throw ClassCastException at run-time

    o = (String) 42; // DOESN'T COMPILE!!!
```

The last line is analogous to your cast from a primitive directly to an unknown parameterized type `T` (i.e. `(T) Integer.parseInt(s)`), which is why it doesn't compile. It's true that you're trying to write the code such that `T` would be the proper type, but there's no way of confirming that at compile-time, since `T` can be any type in general.

The previous to last line gets around the compile-time error by **indirectly** casting the primitive to `String`, after it had already been converted to an `Object` reference type. That's why it compiles, although of course it will throw a `ClassCastException` at run-time.

Here's a parameterized type generic example: it's a bit silly, but reillustrates the problem with casting primitives **directly** to an unknown reference type:

```
<T> T f() {
    //return (T) 42; // DOESN'T COMPILE!!!
    return (T) (Integer) 42; // compiles with warning about unchecked cast
}
```

#### References

- [Java language guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [JLS 5.1.7 Boxing conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7)
- [JLS 5.1.8 Unboxing conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8)
- [JLS 5.1.5 Widening reference conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.5)

Comment: +1 @polygenelubricants : Thanks for pointing out how to avoid the compiler warnings. I'll be using this.

Comment: +check @polygenelubricants : Thanks for the update to your answer - it is much clearer to me now!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you want:

```
    if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class))
    {
        value = (T)Boolean.valueOf(Boolean.parseBoolean(str));
    } else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class))
    {
        value = (T)Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(str));
    } else if (clasz.isAssignableFrom(Float.class))
    {
        value = (T)Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(str));
    }
```

The issue was that your code was fooling the autoboxing, so the compiler was not converting the primitive `boolean` to a `Boolean` instance automatically.  I put in explicit conversions and voila.  The code complains about unchecked casts, but that's unavoidable so you'll want to @SuppressWarnings

Comment: +1 & check @Chris Dolan :Thanks for explaining what the underlying cause was. I was really confused since I had already declared `<T extends Object>` in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is probably to just treat things, in particular the value variable and the map, as Object, and then have a final cast to (T) at the return of the method.

You'll get a bunch of unchecked warnings, but you're going to get those anyway...